# JQuery Input box focus problem

Tags: jquery, focus, inputbox

I want to check some condition on blur of input box in jQuery. Once I lose focus from Input box I am not able to get focus again to that box.

Code:

```
if ($("#Amount").val() < 10000) { 
    alert('The minimum amount is $10,000.'); 
    $("#Amount").focus();
} 
else {
}
```

Once i lose focus from `$("#Amount")` it's not setting focus to that control.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you brief your question???... Can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is what you are looking for, I believe: http://jsfiddle.net/6Seks/5/

**Edit:** just noticed how close my answer is to [Scroobler's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496481/jquery-input-box-focus-problem/#5496662), though mine doesn't suffer the larger than 10000 bug his does.

Comment: Cara !! Salvou minha vida hahaha `+1`

Answer (score 1):

[`.focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) in jQuery will focus on the element, but won't give access to the text input when its within a [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event. You can use the `.setTimeout()` function to call the focus so it happens just after the [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) event:

```
$("#Amount").blur(function() {
    if ($("#Amount").val() < 10000) { 
        alert('The minimum amount is $10,000.'); 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#Amount").focus();
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

However, I would suggest changing things a little more to check the use has actually input a number as well:

```
$("#Amount").blur(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    if (isNaN(obj.val()) || obj.val() < 10000) { 
        $('#result').html('The minimum amount is $10,000.'); 
        setTimeout(function() {
            obj.focus();
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

See it in [**action here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CxGac/1)

**Corrected as per [Levi Morrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538216/levi-morrison)'s comment**

Comment: @Scroobler This won't work mate... put in a number greater than 10000 and it still doesn't work.  See my code (http://jsfiddle.net/6Seks/5/) and try if you can see what you did wrong ;)

Comment: LoL - nice spot on the mistake! I'll blame the coffee not kicking in yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this:

```
$("#Amount").blur(function() {
    if ($(this).val() < 10000) {
        alert('your message...');
        $(this).focus();
    }
})
```

Comment: It doesn't focus.  You have to set a timeout on the focus.  Irritating, really, but yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure if i understand what you are looking for.
If you what do disable an input box after doing something you can use:

jquery

```
$("#Amount").prop("disabled", true);
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("Amount").disabled = true;
```

so it would be something like:

```
$("#Amount").change(function() { 
    if (this.value > 10000) {
        alert('The minimum amount is $10,000.');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Amount").disabled = true;
    };
})
```

...sorry if this isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking.